# Adding VFACE semantic causes overlapping output semantics error

Tags: hlsl, culling

My pixel shader input is a follows

```
struct VertexShaderOut
{
    float4 Position                 : POSITION0;    
    float2 TextureCoordinates       : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 PositionClone            : TEXCOORD1;        // Final position values must be cloned to be used in PS calculations
    float3 Normal                   : TEXCOORD2;
    //float3x3 TBN                  : TEXCOORD3;
    float CullFace                  : VFACE;            // A negative value faces backwards (-1), while a positive value (+1) faces the camera (requires ps_3_0)
};
```

I'm using ps_3_0 and I wish to utilise the VFACE semantic for correct lighting of normals depending on the cull mode.

If I add the VFACE semantic then I get the following errors:

> error X5639: dcl usage+index: position,0 has already been specified for an output register
>   error X4504: overlapping output semantics

Why would this occur?  I can't see why there would be too much data.

EDIT:

Vertex Shader:

```
VertexShaderOut VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderIn input)
{
VertexShaderOut Output = (VertexShaderOut)0;

// 'input.Position.w' should always equal 1
input.Position.w = 1;

// [Transformation]
// • Multiplying input.Position by World, then the result by ViewProjection is fast
// • Concatenating World and ViewProjection matrices then multiplying input.Position by the result is slower
input.Position = mul(input.Position, World);        
Output.Position = mul(input.Position, ViewProjection);

// [Texel To Pixel Align] 
// • Half pixel offset for correct texel centering)
// • Should be done AFTER transformation
Output.Position.xy -= HalfPixelTexel.xy;

// [Texel To Pixel Align] 
// • Adjust uv coordinates so they use the correct texture from the texture atlas  
Output.TextureCoordinates = input.TextureCoordinates;

// [Normal]
// • Use world transform with normals to avoid problems with different coordinate systems
Output.Normal = mul(float4(input.Normal.xyz, 0), World).xyz;

//Output.TBN[0] = normalize(mul(input.Tangent, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));             // X Axis
//Output.TBN[1] = normalize(mul(input.BiTangent, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));           // Y Axis
//Output.TBN[2] = normalize(mul(input.Normal, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));              // Z Axis

// [Position Clone]
// • POSITION0 values can't be used in the pixel shader so they must be passed in via another semantic
Output.PositionClone = Output.Position;

// [VFace]
//Output.CullFace = 0;
//Output.CullFace = sign(dot(ViewInv[3].xyz - Output.Position, Output.Normal));

return Output;
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOut input)
{   
PixelShaderOutput output = (PixelShaderOutput)0;

// [Scale Texture Coordinates] (Page 12 - Texture Atlas Paper)
// • To access all texels of a texture of dimensions 'width' by 'height' once and only once, models need to use:
// • u-coordinates in the range [.5 / width, 1 - (.5 / width)] 
// • v-coordinates in the range [.5 / height, 1- (.5 / height)]
// • This prevents bleeding of textures (like wrapping) when using an atlas

// Scaling method - Works with both quadrangles and arbitrary geometry with original uv coordinates between 0 and 1
float s = (BackBufferDim - 1.0f) / BackBufferDim;
float o = 0.5f / BackBufferDim;
input.TextureCoordinates.xy *= s;
input.TextureCoordinates.xy += o;

// Wrap coordinates in [0, 1) range (for both tiling and scrolling)
// Use 'frac(texCoord) * n' to wrap in [0, n) range
float2 texCoords0 = frac(input.TextureCoordinates.xy); //* input.NumTiles.xy);
float2 texCoords1 = frac(input.TextureCoordinates.xy); //* input.NumTiles.zw);

// Adjust uv coordinates so they use the correct texture from the texture atlas  
texCoords0 = CalculateAtlasUV(texCoords0, SourceRectangle0);
texCoords1 = CalculateAtlasUV(texCoords1, SourceRectangle1);

float4 colour0 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoords0);
float4 colour1 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoords1);

// [Linear Interpolation]
// • Based on colour1 alpha (therefore colour1 takes precedence over colour0)
// • output = lerp(A, B, C);
// • output = A * (1 - C) + B * C;
float4 colour = lerp(colour0, colour1, colour1.a);

// [Flash]
// • Interpolate between final colour and flash colour based on the flash timer value
colour = lerp(colour, float4(1, 1, 1, 1), FlashAmount);

// [Colour]
output.Color = colour;

// [Tangent/Normal]
// • Get value in the range of -1 to 1
//float3 n = 2.0f * tex2D(BumpMapSampler, input.TextureCoordinates) - 1.0f;

// Multiply by the tangent matrix
//n = mul(n, input.Tangent);

// Output normal
output.Tangent.xyz = normalize(input.Normal) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
//output.Tangent *= input.CullFace;
output.Tangent.w = 1;

// [Specular, Glow, Reflection] 
// • Completely optional
//output.SGR.r = tex2D(SpecularSampler, input.TextureCoordinates);
//output.SGR.g = tex2D(GlowSampler, input.TextureCoordinates);
//output.SGR.b = tex2D(ReflectionMap, input.TextureCoordinates);
//output.SGR.w = 0;

// [Depth]
// • Flip to keep accuracy away from floating point issues
output.Depth.r = 1.0f - (input.PositionClone.z / input.PositionClone.w); 
output.Depth.a = 1;

return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, ordinarily the `POSITION0` is not part of the pixel shader input struct, nor `VFACE` part of the vertex shader output.  Try removing those from the struct and adding them as a separate output parameter from the vertex shader, and input parameter to the pixel shader.  It's a little weird, but perhaps internally, `VFACE` uses the same register as `POSITION0` (which would be possible because the former is only for pixel shaders and the latter only for vertex shaders).

That is, your shader prototypes might look something like:

```
struct VertexShaderOut
{
    float2 TextureCoordinates       : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 PositionClone            : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 Normal                   : TEXCOORD2;
    //float3x3 TBN                  : TEXCOORD3;
};

void VertexShaderFunction(
        VertexShaderIn input,
        VertexShaderOut output,
        float4 outPos : POSITION0)
{
    // ...code...
}

void PixelShaderFunction(
        VertexShaderOut input,
        float CullFace : VFACE)
{
    // ...code...
}
```

Comment: If I do that the I get:  error X4541: vertex shader must minimally write all four components of POSITION.  I'll add the original .fx file I am currently using.

Comment: @user1423893 I forgot to mention, `VFACE` should be a separate input parameter for the pixel shader, as well.

Comment: It fixed the problem by using a separate input parameter for the VFACE semantic.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1423893 Glad to hear it!  Don't forget to click the check-mark button next to the answer to mark it as "accepted", for other users.

Comment: Can't see the check mark.  Maybe I'm not looking hard enough or Chrome is not displaying it?  I clicked around the page and voted the answer up though.